# How can I disable GPS/WiFi for all Android apps but one I'm crerating?

Tags: java, android, gps, internet-connection

I'm trying to write app that is using GPS/Internet and want to switch off possibility of using Internet or at least switch off some services like sms,www, etc. Is it possible to programmatically disable this services for all other apps but mine?

Comment: This is obviously not possible, and for very simple reasons... imagine the abuses.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot turn these types of services off from within your app (and I don't know why you would want to). Taken [from the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html):

> Global system settings, containing preferences that always apply
>   identically to all defined users. Applications can read these but are
>   not allowed to write; like the "Secure" settings, these are for
>   preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI
>   or specialized APIs for those values.